# Will my Kentia Palm die?

Tags: houseplants, diagnosis, indoors, palm, kentia

I have two Kentia palms that I’ve had for a couple months now, and they’ve been doing really well with a lot of new growth - until yesterday when I noticed these brown, and crispy leaves at the bottom of one.

What caused it? I water the palms every 1.5-2 weeks (once I felt the top few cm of the soil dry), and it receives indirect light.

I used to take the nursery pot out of the decorative pot and water the palm directly in the bath tub - but now I have two it’s a little hard, so I’ve been watering them both straight in the pot, then taking it out of the decorative pot after a while (usually no more than 5 min) and putting it on a towel and drying the inside of decorative pot before putting it back in. They’re quite big so it’s hard to move them a lot.

However, I'm worried though that I may have left the nursery pot inside the decorative pot for 20 or so minutes the last time I watered them (I had an emergency and was distracted)- is that enough time for root rot??

I've cut all the brown, crispy stems off, at the base. Will whatever caused it spread to the rest of the palm?

Any advice would be much appreciated as I adore my palms :(

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: also should note that I regularly mist my palms, and only one of them is affected (and its the one that was left for a little longer).

Comment: If it were root rot, or the beginning of it, how do I fix it? Let it dry out completely? the rest of the leaves seem fine, its just the one, smallest shoot that was affected